# Glyphicons don't work when I run bower install on bootstrap 3.2.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I have the following in my fonts folder:

- glyphicons-halflings-regular
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
- glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

(Path:C:\Users\smitha\Code\proj\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\fonts)

But glyphicons like `glyphicon-search` are not loading!

```
 <div tabindex="6" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">...<.div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't appear to have the full set of font files. A complete set should include the following 5 files:

1. glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
2. glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
3. glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
4. glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
5. glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Second, unless you take steps to specifically identify the location of the font files, the standard location is assumed to be a `/fonts` folder that is a sibling to the directory that contains your `bootstrap.js`. For example, using the location of the `/fonts` directory in your posting:

> C:\Users\smitha\Code\proj\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\fonts

Your Bootstrap JavaScript library should be located at:

> C:\Users\smitha\Code\proj\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\js\bootstrap-3.2.0.min.js

It doesn't matter whether that folder is actually named `/js`; it could be named anything; the important part is that it is a **sibling** to the `/font` folder. You don't mention the location of your Bootstrap library, but my guess is that it isn't in a directory that is a sibling to your `/font` directory.

If this doesn't help you to resolve the problem, you may want to include more information about your full project directory structure, especially the location of the Bootstrap JavaScript library.

Comment: Yep. I debugged more and found - my fonst is located here:C:\Users\smitha\code\proj\bower_components\bootstrap\dist\fonts But i get the 404 as - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -
http://localhost:8626/ui/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff. I am not sure why wrong path has been taken and how to correct it

Comment: If you add more detail about the full layout of your project, include the contents of any deployment configuration files, and maybe details about how you are using `bower`. It's hard to tell without those details. But you will have to include some of those details to get the problem resolved.

Comment: Thanks Sean..that's confidential.

Comment: I know it's super late, but the reason is because the server you are running (probably a jetbrains product) isn't serving them